# Symplectic (or alike) integrator for system with Coulomb singularity and time-dependent potentials

Tags: differential-equations, sg.symplectic-geometry, classical-mechanics, hamiltonian-mechanics, numerical-integration

I am trying to calculate classical trajectories for a single a ion and a single electron inside an RF trap. Therefore, I am dealing with a two-body system that possesses:

- Coulomb potential with a singularity
- time-dependent potential that is periodic in time and quadratic in space (smooth, relatively weak - compared to the Coulomb). However, asymptotically it becomes dominant.

I would like to calculate the classical trajectories that start from an arbitrary point in the phase space. The time interval I am interested in, is up to 10 periods of the trap field.

I've had some limited success with Tao's symplectic integrator for charged particle in electromagnetic fields. However, the number of time steps necessary to get converged trajectories, is quite large and I would need to perform some systematic scan of the parameter space.

Is there any more appropriate integrator for this kind of situations please? Should I try to regularize the Coulomb singularity first? Thanks for any hint.

Comment: You might get some more answers on [scicomp.stackexchange.com](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com). I'm kind of guessing here, but it's pretty hard to avoid having severe timestep restrictions with explicit methods. Although the cost of an individual timestep might be higher because of the nonlinear system solve, you might have better results going to an implicit symplectic scheme because you can take much larger timesteps.